# RestKit Dynamic Mapping with heterogeneouse collections and Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have the following JSON structure which I want to map with RestKit in CoreData:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "folder",
    "name": "Folder 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "document",
        "name": "Document 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "folder",
        "name": "Folder 2",
        "children": [
          {
            "id" : 2,
            "type": "document",
            "name": "Document 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It's a typical filesystem structure where a folder can contain other folders or documents.

I have two CoreData entities: Folder and Document.
The Folder entity has the following relationships:
[image]

Here is my Mapping Code:

```
RKEntityMapping* foldersMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Folder" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
foldersMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"objectId" ];
[foldersMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id" : @"objectId",
                                                     @"name" : @"name"}];

RKEntityMapping* documentsMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
documentsMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"objectId" ];
[documentsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id" : @"objectId",
                                                       @"name" : @"name"}];
```

In my dynamic mapping I use the type of the object to decide if it is a document or a folder.

```
RKDynamicMapping* dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];

[dynamicMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKObjectMapping *(id representation) {

    if ([[representation valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"Folder"]) {
        return foldersMapping;
    } else if ([[representation valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"Document"]) {
        return documentsMapping;
    }

    return nil;
}];
```

Now I added the dynamic mapping as relationship mapping to the folder mapping for the property children two times.

```
[foldersMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"children" toKeyPath:@"children" withMapping:dynamicMapping]];
[foldersMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"children" toKeyPath:@"documents" withMapping:dynamicMapping]];
```

And here is my Problem: All this works, but I got the following Warnings:

> RestKitNesterFolderTestProject[9969:3a03] W
>   restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:554 WARNING: Failed
>   mapping nested object: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa
>   error 1550.)

I think the Problem is that I doubled the mapping for the relationship children, so RestKit tries to map each child two times, once as Folder and once as Document.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to maintain 2 entities in your model? Can you use a single entity, with a children relationship to itself and a type attribute? Mapping the current JSON to current model isn't very easy...

Comment: The problem is that the CoreData model already exists and I can't change it unless breaking other functionality of the app.

Comment: And name isn't guaranteed to be globally unique and you don't have another unique identifier? I'm not convinced that RestKit can really help you...

Comment: No, name is not unique. I have a unique identifier, but I left it out for the example to keep it simple.

Comment: Ok, add the unique id info as that is the only thing which might make it workable

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I added unique ids to the JSON and the entities.

Comment: Thinking about this more and I don't think it can be done. Every option I think of has some issue with unknown tree depth or associating a folder where a document is expected. You either need to change the JSON, or the model, or do the parsing outside RestKit...

Comment: Okay, thank you anyway. Maybe I change the JSON so that folders have a children and a documents property.